# When is the exponential map injective on generic subspaces?

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

If you take a flat 2-torus $\mathbb{T}$ and a random 1-dimensional subspace $V \subseteq T_e \mathbb{T}$ (where $e$ is an arbitrary basepoint), then generically the exponential map is injective.

This fails already for a round 2-sphere, but what is driving this? That is, what can we say implies or is implied by the following conditions:

- $X$ a Riemannian $n$-manifold
- $e$ a basepoint for $X$
- $d < n$ (maybe $d < \sqrt{n}$ even)
- $\mathrm{exp}_e$ is injective on a generic $d$-dimensional subspace of $T_e X$

I'd be very curious (even more so actually) in the case that $X$ is a Lie group.

Could it have something to do with non-positive curvature? In the case of the n-sphere the failure seems to be driven by the kind of focusing of geodesics I associate with positive curvature. Although I suppose it is easily explained by the transitivity of the isometry group on the tangent space. This seems promising since the torus has countable isometry group.

Comment: In the case $d = 1$, with $X$ a compact Lie group, the condition that $\exp$ be generically injective is equivalent to the condition that $\exp$ is injective for at least one subspace, which is equivalent to the dimension of a maximal torus being $> 1$. The technical piece is just to check that uniformly choosing a maximal torus and then uniformly picking a direction tangent to that torus is suitably compatible with the original notion of generic subspace.